Pyinstaller: importError Could not load the python extension module
I've created an app to handle a camera, using two libraries from the manufacturer.
I've downloaded the wheel files and installed them in my venv with
pip install ids_peak-1.7.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
pip install ids_peak_ipl-1.10.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Everything works correctly in pycharm.
I try to create an exe file with pyinstaller. I installed pyinstaller in my venv and then in the terminal I do:
pyinstaller -F -w -i IDS.ico main.py

When I run the exe file I get this error:

ImportError: Could not load the python extension module! Either the
shared library "ids_peak_ipl" could not be found or the library
version you are using is older than the bindings (expected v1.10.0.0)

The warn-main file contain this:
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by ids_peak.ids_peak (optional), ids_peak_ipl.ids_peak_ipl (optional), ids_peak.ids_peak_ipl_extension (optional) 
missing module named _peak_ipl_python_interface - imported by ids_peak_ipl.ids_peak_ipl (conditional)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional) 
missing module named _ids_peak_ipl_python_extension - imported by ids_peak.ids_peak_ipl_extension (conditional) 
missing module named _ids_peak_python_interface - imported by ids_peak.ids_peak (conditional)

I don't know pyinstaller very well, what should I do?

I'm not familiar with the custom libraries you're using, but somehow or another, the packages or some artifact(s) the packages produce are somehow not being bundled along with your executable. I'd probably check out this related answer on adding data files.
The source code from pip-installed dependencies is usually not a problem, but the issue is when the packages do special things like building artefacts or other files. I've had to do this myself once as I was using a package that dynamically generated an SSL certificate at runtime, but I needed that cert to be bundled in the executable itself. I accomplished this by building the executable with:
pyinstaller -F my_program.py --add-data="$(python3 -c "from CertPackage import cert; print(cert()):CertPackage")"


I've tried to mimic your code with pyinstaller -w -i IDS.ico main.py --add-data="$(python3 -c "from ids_peak_ipl import ids_peak_ipl; print(ids_peak_ipl())":ids_peak_ipl" but I think it lacks a " and I get an error "Wrong syntax"

@Medestrac My bad, made a typo, haha. Should be fixed now.
